# Shift rotated GeoTIFF

Tags: qgis, gdal, rotate

I have images that are rotated (pixels are not rectangular in X, Y but rotated ~8°). How do I shift this image and keep the rotation? I don't understand where the rotation information is kept to be able to manipulate the rotation as well as the corner coordinates. When I use GDAL Translate to shift the corner coordinates, it loses rotation. I've also tried georeferencing in QGIS without success. The top image is the original, image below is the result when I try to shift the image.

It's projected in WGS84 UTM.

[image: Rotated and Non-Rotated image comparison]

Update: The gdalinfo output for the original image:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Size is 4980, 4200
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 29N",
    ID["EPSG",32629]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
GeoTransform =
  179350.2052162796, 14.82222284696933, -2.302544217768792
  1532187.652681859, -2.302544217768792, -14.82222284696933
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  179350.205, 1532187.653) ( 11d57'57.71"W, 13d50'29.52"N)
Lower Left  (  169679.520, 1469934.317) ( 12d 2'53.57"W, 13d16'41.96"N)
Upper Right (  253164.875, 1520720.982) ( 11d16'57.62"W, 13d44'42.89"N)
Lower Right (  243494.189, 1458467.647) ( 11d21'59.46"W, 13d10'55.09"N)
Center      (  211422.197, 1495327.650) ( 11d39'57.06"W, 13d30'43.24"N)
```

Update: I've found info on the Geotransform and now I know what those 6 numbers mean, but I'm still curious what the best way to unrotate, shift and then rotate would be.

Comment: Please add a gdalinfo report from one source image.